# C language int num to char string

Tags: c, string, int, type-conversion

How do I get from:

```
int i = 1023
```

to:

```
char string[4] = "1023"
```

Here's my attempted code:

#### Attempt 1

```
#include <stdio.h>

main(){

    int avg_adc = 1023;
    char myString[4];
    sprintf(myString, "%d", avg_adc); 
}  
//Output returned 4
```

#### Attempt 2

```
main(){

    int avg_adc = 1023;
    char myString[4];
    snprintf(myString, 4, "%d", avg_adc); 
}  
//Output returned 4
```

Does these outputs not make `myString == char myString[4] = "1023";` ?

I'm just really confused how to get the output I need.

Comment: "1023" is a five symbol string. You are allocating only four on the stack.

Comment: What do you mean? Your code doesn't output anything.

Comment: Yeah I realized that while troubleshooting. I ended up going another method but I appreciate the help.

Comment: If your own solution solves this question, you are free to add it as an answer (and [even encouraged](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)).

Answer (score 9):

You need to allocate 5 elements for myString ('1','0','2','3','\0')

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
  int avg_adc = 1023;
  char myString[5];
  sprintf(myString, "%d", avg_adc);
  printf("%s\n", myString);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I ended up going with a different method but I appreciate the help. I knew I was close.. rip

Comment: @Arch Sure no problem.  If it helps you should accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

From ISO C11 draft n1570:

> The `sprintf` function returns the number of characters written in the array,
>   not counting the terminating null character, or a negative value if an
>   encoding error occurred.

In other words, the return value of

```
sprintf(myString, "%d", 1023);
```

is indeed 4, but it actually writes **5** characters to `myString`. More is revealed with `snprintf`, which limits the number of characters written to the specified value, and this number should account for the terminating null character:

> Thus, the null-terminated output has been completely written if and only
>   if the returned value is nonnegative and less than [the specified limit].

```
int avg_adc = 1023;
char myString[4];
int charsWritten;

charsWritten = snprintf(myString, sizeof(myString), "%d", avg_adc);
if (charsWritten >= 0 && charsWritten < sizeof(myString)) {
    printf("OK :-)\n");
} else {
    printf("TROUBLE :-(\n");
    printf("Returned: %d\n", charsWritten);
    printf("myString=%s, expected %d\n", myString, avg_adc);
}
```

Output on my system:

```
TROUBLE :-(
Returned: 4
myString=102, expected 1023
```

In other words, you need to check the return value of `snprintf`. If the test fails, then your result string was truncated, and it needs to be one character larger than the return value to fit all of the characters that you want it to store, assuming a negative value isn't returned. Declaring `char myString[5];` results in the following output:

```
OK :-)
```

Answer (score 0):

The in-memory representation of `myString` would look like this:

```
            --- --- --- --- ---
myString:  | 1 | 0 | 2 | 3 |\0 |
            --- --- --- --- ---
```

i.e. `char` arrays are terminated by a null character `'\0'`, for which you forgot to allocate memory.

In your code, if you want to store `int avg_adc = 1023;`, you should account for the one extra `char` and define the array as:

```
char myString[5];
```

Answer (score -2):

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
        int avg_adc = 1023;
        char myString[4];
        sprintf(myString, "%d", avg_adc);
        printf("%s",myString); //you forgot this..
}
```

Comment: if this answer is useful,
please accept this answer

Comment: You're storing a 5-character string in a 4-character array.

Comment: However, the question asks why there is no output. The absence of output functions in the question _does_ explain that...

Comment: @NisseEngström  run it  ,this program gives perfect output after tell anything ....